# How to only fetch the document with changes made form firebase with snapshot listener in swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection that I attach a snapshot listener to. Problem is when I change a document in this collection it refetch all the documents in the collection, not just the one that changed.
This is my code when I set the snapshot listener

```
let docRef = db.collection("users").document(userID).collection("Platser")
        docRef.addSnapshotListener { [weak self] snapshot, error in
            guard let data = snapshot, error == nil else {
                return
            }
```

Inside .collection("Platser") is the collection for each "Plats" That have an auto-generated id from firebase as name.

If I change one document I just want to refetch that specific document, else the reads will go up way to high on a real app with users.

Been trying different ways to solve this and tried to read the firebase docs for this but I'm new to firebase and I really can't solve this one right now.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The answer by @loremipsum is accurate but let me add a bit of context; When an listener is added `addSnapshotListener`, your app is notified of any changes, and also presented the type of change and what changed as well - there is no need to re-fetch anything. The diff in `snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in` contains the type of change `diff.type == .modified` for example and the actual data that changed `diff.document.data()`. Does that clarify? Note that when a listener is first added, it will read everything that matches the query, and only present changes thereafter.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies a bit more for me. I'm still kinda confused after watching videos and documentation from firebase saying that my listener will only make reads when something changes. 
I did exactly their suggestion on setting up a listener to a document and it rereads every time the app have been offline for like 15 minutes and I reopen it. 

Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but copied their code and been trying so many different ways of doing this.

Imo I feel like their documentation is really easy to make the app work like you want, but not good explanation on how to actually cut reads

Comment: Let's rephrase this *that my listener will only make reads when something changes*. What actually happens is when there's an event on the server, the server sends that event & data to your app. Mind you there are different kinds of listeners so you would only implement those you're interested in. Keeping data fresh is one of the features of Firestore which makes it live and responsive. Adding listeners notifies the app with a data snapshot whenever the data you're listening to changes, retrieving only the new changes. If it's retrieving ALL data, then the code is wrong and we need to see it.